# Can a Fillable PDF file be convereted to an XPS file and still remain a fillable form?

Tags: c#, pdf, xps

Can a fillable PDF file be converted to an XPS file and still remain a fillable form? All Google seems to show is a ton of companies that want to sell me converters. And none of them can answer my question. I'm looking to use the "fields" set up in a fillable PDF file to populate a database app written in C#. From what I understand XPS has the ability to do this. Plus it seems cheaper than using Adobe's $5000/year sdk.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the PDF is no longer a PDF then that feature set is gone. However, you can COPY the PDF and convert the copy so that you have both a PDF and XPS, but they are not 'in sync'. One the other hand you can have the fun of writing the code to keep them in sync...

You may want to look at packaging both files in container (like a cab or zip file of your own devising) a .JIM file that contains both resources... but that might be overkill.